# Is possible to see junk mail from mail.com server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using happily Outlook 2016 with mail.com server but I also would like to see the junk mail in Outlook as I do on mail.com web site. Currently the "Junk E-mail" folder on Outlook is empty. How can I configure it to show the junk e-mail?

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to make Outlook show you the Junk Mail folder that's on the mail.com server:

1. Configure your email account in Outlook as an IMAP account
2. Configure your email account in Outlook as an Exchange account

Whichever option you use, the mail server needs to support the account type. If it does not, then you cannot get Outlook to show the content of the Junk Mail folder that's on the server.

Comment: YES. I use Outlook, for years now. Always IMAP. I see all my junkmail. Unfortunately :)